# Simulate mod_rewrite using JS/JQUERY/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess, which am I using to rewrite my URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /home [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1&product=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

**Is it possible to rewrite links like that in JS/JQUERY/PHP? (or, for example, call mod_rewrite externally)**

Comment: i think you need to explain why you would want to do this

Comment: *"Is it possible to rewrite links like that in JS/JQUERY/PHP?"* Yes, it is entirely possible, however, it's not very clean/efficient.

Comment: Dagon: I am using standard php and .htaccess for "pretty URL" for googlebot and AJAX silent calls for user browsing. Until now, I had quite simple link structure with only one variable, so it was easy to simulate this behavior.

Comment: that really does not explain much

Comment: I am not very skilled in programming, so my current solution might not be optimal. Until now, when user clicked on link, I grabbed the pretty URL (domain.com/category1) and modified it so the AJAX call was like (ajax.php?cat=category1)

Comment: If you dont understand, please explain what. I will try to make it clear :)

Comment: I can think of a use case for this. Say you have no access to server side and you can only edit your html or php file. Then say you are loading an external library that then goes and fetches external resources that take a long time to retrieve because they may be hosted in a less optimal place. You might want to preload these resources from a local copy by capturing the request for them and redirecting it to your local copy which is faster to download.